# PHP code getting printed in browser on runnning Apache Web App

Tags: apache, php-7

I am using php 7 and Apache 2 for running my local web server. I am, however, facing a weird issue of php code getting printed on the browser instead of it getting executed.

[image]

I have tried all the suggested fixes I could find online but none of them seem to work. Here is a link to my httpd.conf file for reference:

https://gofile.io/d/TPfXGq

Comment: I suppose that the app should located inside of  "/usr/local/opt/httpd" you can verify your httpd.conf **ServerRoot "/usr/local/opt/httpd"**

Comment: @seddikomar that did not work, it should not actually. ServerRoot is the path to the webserver executable and not the files to be executed.